# css button fix with input submit button

Tags: css

I have a button which works well with the anchor tag but does not work with the submit input tag. How can i make this work with submit button ?

```
.classname {
     -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
     -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
     box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
     background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
     background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
     background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
     border-radius:6px;
     border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
     display:inline-block;
     color:#777777;
     font-family:arial;
     font-size:15px;
     font-weight:bold;
     padding:6px 24px;
     text-decoration:none;
     text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
.classname:hover {
     background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
     background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
     background-color:#dfdfdf;
}
.classname:active {
     position:relative;
     top:1px;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work fine with `<input type="submit" class="classname">`, Check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HVxpW/

Comment: `input`, `button` and `anchor` all look the same to me with your css. The only difference I can note is that the `cursor` type for anchor tags. http://jsfiddle.net/HVxpW/2/ You should probably be more specific with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first started learning about inputs and got to the Submit i thought it crashes and the submit doesn't work. Actually it turned that only the `cursor` changes. Try to set the button style `cursor: pointer`.